# UV Unwrap shortcut not working!

Tags: uv, shortcut

I'm simply trying to UV wrap a sphere to add a texture onto it. However, whenever I press <kbd>U</kbd>, rather than prompting which UV settings I want *Make single user* pops up, which is very frustrating.
I've looked in the user preferences and found nothing. I've been using Blender for a while now but not very much on my current computer, so maybe something's changed. I'm using Cycles (of course) - I would appreciate if someone can tell me what I need to do.

Comment: are you in edit mode? and have you changed the default keymap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are in *Object* mode, switch to *Edi*t mode

Comment: I would say post very very short solutions such as this one as a comment.

Comment: @Amir If an answer is very simple it will sometimes be very short.